# Как в yii2 лучше сделать выборку из бд, используя rest api?

Tags: yii2, rest

Использую ActiveController как написано в документации.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;        
    $developer = Developers::findOne([
        'id' => Yii::$app->request->get('developer_id'),
    ]);
    $complex_type = ComplexType::findOne([
        'id' => Yii::$app->request->get('complex_id'),
    ]);
    $complex = Complex::findOne([
        'type_id' => $complex_type->id,
        'developer_id' => $developer->id,
    ]);
    $query = $modelClass::find()
    ->where(
        [
            'amount_room' => Yii::$app->request->get('amount_room'),
            'yardage' => Yii::$app->request->get('yardage'),
            'level' => Yii::$app->request->get('level'),
            'complex_id' => $complex->id,
        ]);
    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: Сейчас обязательно нужно передавать все параметры, что в принципе логично. Каким способом сделать проверку на заполненность параметра, и уже в зависимости от это делать поиск? Я могу сделать кучу if'ов но получится не очень красиво. Как лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать filterWhere, andFilterWhere и orFilterWhere, если заданное значение будет пусто, то условие будет игнорироваться.

```
// $username и $email вводит пользователь
$query->filterWhere([
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
]);
```

Подробнее можно узнать здесь [https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-query-builder.md#Условия-для-фильтров-](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-query-builder.md#%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-)

Comment: Да, как раз начал рыть в эту сторону. Видимо по невнимательности не увидел этот метод. Спасибо